# Can't assign item value to property list in c#

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I have my model class, like this:

```cs
        public class Info
        {
            public string status { get; set; }
        }

        public class MyItem
        {
            public MyItem()
            {
                info = new List<Info>();
            }
            public List<Info> info { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string address { get; set; }
            public int? age { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            public List<MyItem> data { get; set; }
        }
```

I'm using RestSharp to get json file then deserialize it to my model. Then I wanna assign new item inside my info list properties. But I got no values inside the `info` list:

```json
{
"data": [
{
   "info": [],
   "name": "John Doe",
   "address": "2541 Cheshire Road",
   "age": null
},
.
.
.
```

Here is my code so far:

```cs
            var client = new RestClient("XXX");
            client.UseNewtonsoftJson();
            var request = new RestRequest("XXX");
            var response = client.Execute(request);

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response.Content);
            var foo = new MyItem();
            foreach (var item in result.data)
            {
                var total = 0;
                total = item.GetType()
                    .GetProperties()
                    .Select(x => x.GetValue(item, null))
                    .Count(v => v is null || (v is string a && 
                     string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a)));

                foo.info.Add(new Info() { status = "test" }); // add to list here

            }
            return Ok(result);
```

I don't know if I make a mistake, but I think I've been right so far. I've read some similar question, but still I can't figure it out how to solve this problem.

Comment: @zaggler yes, that's why I added `foo.info.Add(new Info() { status = "test" });` but I ended up with null list `[]`

Comment: @zaggler `item.info.Add(new Info() { status = "test" });` works fine

Comment: @zaggler i added new item to new object and then return the deserialize one, idk if this my mistake, but tbh it cost me much times

Comment: FYI, there's no point in assigning `0` to `total` if you're just going to reassign it on the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding an element to a new instance of `MyItem`, not to any instances within `result`.  Get rid of `foo` entirely and just add it to the element(s) in `result`:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response.Content);
foreach (var item in result.data)
{
    var total = 0;
    total = item.GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Select(x => x.GetValue(item, null))
        .Count(v => v is null || (v is string a && 
         string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a)));

    // Add to "item", not to "foo"
    item.info.Add(new Info() { status = "test" });

}
return Ok(result);
```